# Rollback Transaction SQL

Tags: python, iis, transactions, rollback, sql-server-profiler

I have a IIS hosted Python application and the front application always failed to save.

I noticed that there are a lots of transaction count more than 0 then rollback when SQL Profiler running and those application name is IIS.

Sometime it did commit when transaction count more than 0 as well.

I wondering what does that mean and where can I locate the script that execute this control.

Will it be caused by query design problem? Much appreciate for any advice.

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

says to rollback if there is any transaction active.

That's probably not what you want!

I suspect what you actually want is this:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Hard to know what the question is about.  It seems likely the OP is using T-SQL, either the MSSQL Server or Sybase dialects.  Conceivably the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` logic could be useful in error handling, see [MSSQL's `TRY...CATCH` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) for testing `XACT_STATE` for uncommittable transactions.

Comment: hi Mitch, I noticed that quite a lot of transaction rollback found in SQL Profiler. Especially when end user saving records in the same time in front end application.

Comment: hi hardmath, but the rollback ended up by causing frontend application failed to save.